# s3 file access denied for large files using cyberduck

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cyberduck

When I use a custom policy below, I get the following error when uploading large files (1G and over) using cyberduck

> file access denied. please contact your web hosting service provider
>   for assistance

However uploading small files (around 200M) is not an issue, also I have no issue creating new folders and files with cyberduck and the same login credentials. So the I definitely have a read/write access.

Also if I add a pre defined policy (AmazonS3FullAccess), then uploading of large files also works OK. I'm a bit lost here. How is my policy restricts large file uploads? What am I missing?

my policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::photoshoot2016"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::photoshoot2016/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

AmazonS3FullAccess policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kept digging around and found that Amazon recommends to use multipart uploads for all files over 100M (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html), which I guess what cyberduck is done.

All I had to do in the end is to add missing permissions (ListMultipartUploadParts and ListBucketMultipartUploads) to enable the multipart uploads. Now my policy looks like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::photoshoot2016"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::photoshoot2016/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I found the main clue by enabling bucket logging which which had a lot of "AccessDenied 243" errors for REST.GET.UPLOADS. Amazon's Policy Simulator came very useful as well to figure out what was missing and where it should be placed.